# Intent.ACTION_CALL falla en android 6+

Tags: android

**MI CASO**

1. Tengo este método para realizar llamada directa desde android:

   ```
   public void Llamar(String Numero) {  
       Intent Llamada = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
       Llamada.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Numero));  
       context.startActivity(Llamada);  
   }
   ```
2. El permiso correspondiente esta activado.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
   ```

**EL PROBLEMA**
En terminales con Android menor que 6, funciona correctamente, en terminales con 6 o mayor la aplicación se detiene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para aplicaciones con OS Android anteriores a 6.0 es suficiente con definir el permiso dentro de tu archivo   `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

---

#### Requerir permisos CALL_PHONE en dispositivos con Android 6.0 o posterior.

Este sería la forma adecuada para requerir [permisos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D)) para realizar llamadas telefónicas en `Android 6.0` :

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas!");
    }
```

---

Para validar la petición por API se realiza lo siguiente:

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

...


if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Se tiene permiso
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PrincipalActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
}else{
    // No se necesita requerir permiso OS menos a 6.0.
}
```

En la misma activity agrega el método [onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D))()  que es un callback para obtener el resultado de la petición:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // El usuario acepto los permisos.
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Gracias, aceptaste los permisos requeridos para el correcto funcionamiento de esta aplicación.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                // Permiso denegado.
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se aceptó permisos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
```

Comment: Lo probare y te aviso si funcionara. Gracias

Comment: claro, en este caso para android 6.0, tienes que requerir permisos manualmente para usar CALL_PHONE. De hecho en el LogCat se mostraria esta sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

A partir de Android 6.0 (API 23) hubieron varios cambios en este sentido, entre ellos, algunos permisos han sido considerados como **riesgosos**, y precisamente entre ellos se encuentran los intentos de llamadas telefónicas (`CALL_PHONE`).

Dice la [**documentación de Android**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> A partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios conceden
>   permisos a las apps mientras se ejecutan, no cuando instalan la app.
>   Este enfoque simplifica el proceso de instalación de la app, ya que el
>   usuario no necesita conceder permisos cuando instala o actualiza la
>   app. También brinda al usuario mayor control sobre la funcionalidad de
>   la app; por ejemplo, un usuario podría optar por proporcionar a una
>   app de cámara acceso a esta, pero no a la ubicación del dispositivo.
>   El usuario puede revocar los permisos en cualquier momento desde la
>   pantalla de configuración de la app.
>
> Los permisos del sistema se dividen en dos categorías, normal y riesgoso:
>
> - Los permisos normales no ponen en riesgo la privacidad del usuario de
>     forma directa. Si tu app tiene un permiso normal en su manifiesto, el
>     sistema concede el permiso automáticamente.
> - Los **permisos riesgosos**
>     pueden permitir que la app acceda a información confidencial del
>     usuario. Si tu app tiene un permiso normal en su manifiesto, el
>     sistema concede el permiso automáticamente. Si tienes un permiso
>     peligroso, el usuario debe autorizar explícitamente a tu app.
>
> En todas las versiones de Android, tu app debe declarar los permisos
>   normales y peligrosos que necesita en su manifiesto, como se describe
>   en Declaración de permisos. No obstante, el efecto de esa declaración
>   es diferente según la versión del sistema y el nivel de SDK de destino
>   de tu app:
>
> - Si el dispositivo tiene Android 5.1 o una versión anterior, o el nivel
>     de SDK de destino de tu app es el 22 o uno inferior: Si tienes un
>     permiso peligroso en tu manifiesto, el usuario debe conceder el
>     permiso cuando instale la app; si no otorga el permiso, el sistema no
>     instalará la app.
> - Si el dispositivo tiene **Android 6.0** o una versión
>     posterior, y el nivel de SDK de destino de tu app es el 23 o uno
>     posterior: Los permisos deben estar indicados en el manifiesto de la
>     app, y esta debe solicitar cada permiso riesgoso que necesite mientras
>     la app esté en ejecución. El usuario puede conceder o negar cada
>     permiso y la app puede continuar ejecutándose con capacidades
>     limitadas aun cuando el usuario rechace una solicitud de permiso.

[Consultar lista de permisos riesgosos o peligrosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups).

> **Nota**: A partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios pueden revocar permisos desde cualquier app en cualquier momento,
>   aunque la app esté orientada a un nivel de API inferior. Debes probar
>   tu app para verificar que se comporte correctamente cuando no cuente
>   con un permiso necesario, independientemente del nivel de API al que
>   esté orientada tu app.

### Solicitar o verificar permisos

Cada vez que realice una operación que requiera un permiso peligroso, se debe comprobar si el usuario ha concedido ese permiso. Si no lo ha hecho, debe solicitar que se conceda.

Android tiene documentación en español que explica con fragmentos de código cómo realizar estas tareas.

Puedes consultarlo aquí: [**Cómo solicitar permisos durante el tiempo de ejecución**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

#### Comprobar si existen permisos

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
```

#### Solicitar los permisos que se necesitan

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

#### Controlar la respuesta a la solicitud de permisos

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```