# ¿Cómo ejecutar un código USSD desde mi app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Necesito ejecutar códigos USSD desde mi app de tipo: **#222*1#** (almoadilla222estrella1almoadilla)
Estoy trabajando en `Android Studio`. Lo he intentado con el `Intent.ACTION.CALL`:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:#222*1#"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Para llamar a un número normal (123456789) funciona, pero para el caso anterior me pone que **"el número introdicido no es válido**.

¿Qué debo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola realiza lo siguiente para concatenar el valor `"#"`  -> `Uri.encode("#");`

Por ejemplo, para tu caso:

```
String USSD = Uri.encode("#") + "222*1" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + USSD)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es simplemente codificar el caracter `#`, y por medio de un intent realizar la llamada:

```
String USSD = Uri.encode("#") + "222*1" + Uri.encode("#");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +USSD));
```

Es importante comentar que necesitas permisos declarados en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

pero en el caso de dispositivos con sistema operativo mayor a **Android 6.0**, necesitas declararlos manualmente, aquí puedes encontrar como realizarlo:

**[Intent.ACTION_CALL falla en android 6+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55132/95)**

y te sugiero validar que antes de llamar verifique se tengan los permisos, de otra forma no intentar realizar el `intent`, ya que marcara error:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
     Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     return;
}
String USSD = Uri.encode("#") + "222*1" + Uri.encode("#");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +USSD));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

---

> En cuanto al mensaje que comentas, "el número introducido no es
>   válido." debes tener en cuenta que los USSD codes no son soportados en
>   todos los dispositivos, incluso algunos son bloqueados por el carrier,
>   por lo que puedes tener el mensaje "invalid MMI code".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona de esta manera:
Ademas de dar los permisos necesarios...

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL"); 
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:%23222*1%23"));
     startActivity(intent);
```

Suerte...