# ACTION.CALL abre marcador cuando inicia intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy intentando hacer una app que llame al numero 112 cuando le des al botón. No consigo hacer que cuando les des al botón empiece a llamar directamente, sin que se abra el teclado de marcaodor. Aquí añado una captura de mi código. Supongo que deben de ser una o dos lineas pero no consigo hacerlo de ninguna manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien tengo que decir que los permisos están bien. La llamada y todo funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar `ACTION_CALL` necesitas agregar el permiso `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` en el manifest y debes pedirselo en runtime al usuario si es que no lo tiene permitido.

Además de la documentación de Android:

> No se puede utilizar para llamar a números de emergencia. Las
> aplicaciones pueden marcar números de emergencia usando `ACTION_DIAL`

EDIT:

Ejemplo de lo que uso con minSdkVersion 23 - targetSdkVersion 29 (Android 10)

```
if (!num.equals("")) {
    if (num.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num + ""));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} else {
    UserFunctions.mostrarMensaje(context, "No tiene un número de teléfono válido");
}
```

Lo más importante, verifica que efectivamente tenga este permiso activado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que puede pasar es que el número ***112 como dice tu método es de emergencias*** y eso no se puede usar lamentablemente, intenta con otro número para verificar que funciona el método.

Comment: gracias, eso sí. Pero lo que yo necesito saber es como puedo hacer para que cuando le de al botón empiece la llamada. No que se me abra el marcador del teléfono con el numero 112 y el usuario le tenga que dar a llamar.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta para darte lo que me funciona

Comment: Desde Ecuador llama normalmente usando `intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+34112"));` , lo toma como número válido, pero como no tengo saldo, no sé :(

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto, pero para que soporte el esquema agrega un signo "+" , por ejemplo:

Teniendo como ejemplo el teléfono 347555666777, esta sería la definición en el html:

+347555666777

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+347555666777"));
startActivity(i);
```

El problema debe ser el permiso, debes especificarlo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

y además como el permiso [CALL_PHONE es un permiso riesgoso](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CALL_PHONE) debes realizar su petición manual

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas!");
    }
```

Revisa:

[Intent.ACTION_CALL falla en android 6+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55124/intent-action-call-falla-en-android-6/55132#55132)

Answer (score 0):

Después de un tiempo intentándolo, he conseguido hacerlo. Solo hay que ponerle el +34 por delante y funciona. +34112